# How to create new columns as a function of existing columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

To start with, I have a non-linear model, that I would like to perform a lasso regression with:

[image]

My approach to doing this would be to create a new data frame containing all possible combinations of the vectors of variables, which should = J + J^2

In my data I have J=19, that being 19 predictors, so I am hoping to yield 171 columns in total. Using this I can then perform the Lasso regression using Sklearn.

My approach so far has been:

```
for j in df2.iteritems():
  for k in df2.iteritems():
    df3[j*k] = df2[j]*df2[k]
```

This solution doesn't work but it was an example of my thought process. I am also not too sure how to rename the column them each time in the loop, so each column has a unique name.

Comment: @jch you are absolutely correct, I didn't account for double counting, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly then maybe this will work for you.  If not then maybe you can use the concepts to meet your needs.

Create a list with your numeric predictor values:  (I created some representative via `range()`)

```
p19 = range(10,29)
```

Generate all the combinations from that list:

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(p19, 2))
```

Perform the operation you require on each combination of numbers:  (I simply multiply them together)

```
col_vals = [x[0]*x[1] for x in combs]
```

Using the predictor list, create a DF with some column headings:

```
df_p = pd.DataFrame(p19).transpose().rename(columns = lambda x: 'P' + str(x+1))
```

[image]

Using the computed column values, create a values DF with some column headings:

```
df_c = pd.DataFrame(col_vals).transpose().rename(columns = lambda x: 'C' + str(x+1))
```

[image]

Then combine the two DFs:

```
df = pd.concat([df_p,df_c], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Next challenge is to apply it to all 400 obs.